# How do I average two data frames in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames that look like this:

```
c453    1   8268    loc.00001   .   +   1  2  3 5  6 
c453    1   8268    loc.00002   .   +   1  1  4 5  8 
c453    1   8268    loc.00003   .   +   1  1  4 9  8 


c453    1   8268    loc.00001   .   +   2  3  3 2  6 
c453    1   8268    loc.00002   .   +   1  1  4 5  4 
c453    1   8268    loc.00003   .   +   1  1  4 9  8
```

I want to average across these two files to give the following output:

```
c453    1   8268    loc.00001   .   +   1.5  2.5  3 3.5  6 
c453    1   8268    loc.00002   .   +   1  1  4 5  6 
c453    1   8268    loc.00003   .   +   1  1  4 9  8
```

I would like to do this in pandas, as I am new to using pandas. Concatenating the two files I can do, but stuck from there. Any help would be useful.

Comment: groupby + mean will do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with aggregate `mean`, if first 4 columns, what is necessary if duplicates rows in first 4 columns in `df1` or `df2`:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby(df.columns.tolist()[:4]).mean()
```

If not, use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) and divide by `2`:

```
a = df1.set_index(df.columns.tolist()[:4])
b = df1.set_index(df.columns.tolist()[:4])
c = a.add(b).div(2).reset_index()
```

Comment: cheers, in the situation I have 100 columns, it would be however exhaustive to write each one out

Comment: @AlexTrevylan - Check edit, you can pass `df.columns.tolist()[:4]`

Answer (score 3):

Don't concatenate, that just confuses things.  The average of two values is the sum divided by two:

```
df1.set_index(['A', 'B', 'C'], inplace=True)
df2.set_index(['A', 'B', 'C'], inplace=True)
avg = (df1[['D', 'E']] + df2[['D', 'E']]) / 2
```

That assumes the "key" columns are A/B/C and the data columns are D/E.